# Infinite scroll a Meteor subscription instead of onClick

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am currently serving up a collection with an initial 10 records after which a "load more" button, when clicked, will append the next 10 results.

This works perfectly.

Relevant code in the component...

```
const PER_PAGE = 10;

class userList extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.page = 1;
  }

  handleClick() {
    Meteor.subscribe('users', PER_PAGE * (this.page + 1));
    this.page +=1 ;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="user-list">
          {this.props.users.map(user => <UserInfo key={user._id} user={user}/>)}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
          className="btn btn-primary">Load More...</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

But how could I "infinite scroll" this data instead of using a button click? So when the user scrolls down to the last item (or the location of a hidden button) it automatically triggers the new subscription.

Are there any built in Meteor or React methods or will it have to be done with jQuery / vanilla JS with an onScroll handler?

Comment: Why not just search for 'react infinite scroll' or something?

Comment: Do I really need a plug in for this though? My logic is already built, I only need a way to trigger the new subscription onScroll. I know I can do it with jQuery but I'm asking if there is a better approach.

Comment: No, you don't, and not all the results are modules, some are just techniques. That said, in general, other peoples' code has more eyes, more functionality, and fewer bugs than anything a single person creates.

Comment: Ok after a few hours of trying stuff I gave up, installed `react-infinite-scroll` and had it all working in about 20 seconds flat. I guess that's a valuable React lesson learned right there, why build it yourself when somebody else already has! Thanks @DaveNewton I should have listened to you in the first place ;)

Comment: If I had a nickel... I'd have approximately a nickel ;) Glad you got it working-it's one of the great things about the JS ecosystem... Chances are somebody already needed it. Just remember to contribute back when you can :)

Comment: Still learning. I come from a primarily PHP background. Used to building everything myself from scratch instead of loading in often bloated packages that sometimes cause issues with other aspects of the codebase. react is a whole different ballgame, as I'm starting to learn ;)

Comment: Oh there's bloat, unnecessary features, you name it. Still easier.